# google sheets how to create a formula to increment cells excluding text cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a row starting  with number 11 in the first cell then  empty cell, empty cell, the word "text", empty empty empty then "text".... I only want add 5 to the previous cell if the cell is numeric. So in the example the result of the row should be 11 16 21 "text"  26 31 36 "text". Is there any formula that could follow this pattern in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

This one does what you need:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFS(
    COLUMN(A2:2) > MAX(INDEX(COLUMN(A1:1) * --(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:1))))),
      "",
    NOT(ISBLANK(A1:1)),
      A1:1,
    ISBLANK(A1:1),
      $A1 + 5 * (  COLUMN(A2:2)
                 - COUNTIFS(
                     --(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:1)) * NOT(ISNUMBER(A1:1))),
                     SEQUENCE(1, COLUMN(A1:1), 1, 0),
                     COLUMN(A1:1),
                     "<=" & COLUMN(A1:1)
                   )
                )
  )
)
```

[image]